# Oracle SQL user defined function

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I am trying to write Oracle SQL function. The should take country code, min year and max year as inputs and should return table which contains information for that country in the specified years. This is what I tried to write, but I am new to SQL functions. This is how the data looks and I will be glad for any help.
[image]

```
create or replace type african_crisis_row as object(
country_abv varchar(4),
year number(5),
banking_crisis varchar(10)
);

create or replace type t_african_crisis_table as table of african_crisis_row;

create or replace function african_crisis (   
    country_abv in varchar,
    year_min in number,
    year_max in number
)
return t_african_crisis_table as v_ret table t_african_crisis_table;

begin
    select 
       african_crisis_row(country_abv, year)
    bulk collect into
       v_ret
    from
       africancrisisdata
    where
        country_abv = country_abv and year between year_min and year_max;
    return v_ret
end african_crisis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- remove `table` after the `v_ret` declaration.
- Include the 3rd `banking_crisis` value in the call to the `african_crisis_row` object constructor.
- Include `;` statement terminators after the `return` and final `end` statements.
- Don't name the function parameters with the same name as the column values.

*(Oracle uses `VARCHAR2` and `VARCHAR` is an alias to `VARCHAR2`.)*

Something like this:

```sql
create or replace function african_crisis (   
  i_country_abv in varchar2,
  i_year_min    in number,
  i_year_max    in number
) return t_african_crisis_table
as
  v_ret t_african_crisis_table;
begin
  select african_crisis_row(country_abv, year, banking_crisis)
  bulk collect into v_ret
  from  africancrisisdata
  where country_abv = i_country_abv
  and   year between i_year_min and i_year_max;

  return v_ret;
end african_crisis;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=916ce95d5739052073f2c3d7ae779196)*

Comment: @RafaBarragan [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) because `RETURN DATE AS SELECT ...` is invalid syntax in Oracle and there is insufficient context in your comment to work out what you are trying to achieve and, since I can't quite understand what the goal is, I am unsure what to suggest would be a "correct" solution.

Comment: I have created a new question, do you know where i could be wrong? this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74483231/create-calendar-function-in-oracle-using-with-statement